# Get indexOf special characters in ActionScript3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, special-characters, indexof, quote

In ActionScript3 i wanted to get the text between 2 quotes from some HTML using a input index value where i would simply increase the 2nd quote characters value by 1. This would be very simple however i have now noticed using indexOf does not seem to work correctly with quotes and other special characters.

So my question is if you have some HTML style text like this:

```
var MyText:String = '<div style="text-align:center;line-height:150%"><a href="http://www.website.com/page.htm">';
```

How can i correctly get the index of a quote " or other special character?

Currently i try this:

```
MyText.indexOf('"',1)
```

but after 0 it always returns the wrong index value.

Also a quick additional question would be is there a better way than using ' ' to store strings with characters like " inside? So if i had other ' characters etc it won't cause problems.

Edit -

This is the function i had created (usage = GetQuote(MyText,0) etc)

```
        // GetQuote Function (Gets the content between quotes at a set index value)
        function GetQuote(Input:String, Index:Number):String {
            return String(Input.substr(Input.indexOf('"', Index), Input.indexOf('"', Index + 1)));
        }
```

The return for GetQuote(MyText,0) is "text-align yet i need text-align:center;line-height:150% instead.

Comment: If you can make sure the html code is strict-XHTML you might wanna prefer using the XML class instead of dealing with strings. Otherwise you might wanna write a class to handle what you want. A question: Is getting the value of the style attribute sufficient, won't you need to change it also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, index of the first quote is 11 and both `MyString.indexOf('"')` and `MyString.indexOf('"',1)` return the right value (the latter also works because you don't actually have a quote at the beginning of your string).

When you need to use an single quote inside another one or a double quote inside another one you need to escape the inner one(s) using backslashes. So to catch a single quote you would use it like `'\''`

There are several ways of stripping a value from a string. You can use the **RegExp** class or use standard **String** functions like `indexOf`, `substr` etc.

Now what exactly would you like the result to become? Your question is not obvious.

**EDIT:**

Using the `RegExp` class is much easier:

```
var myText:String = '<div style="text-align:center;line-height:150%"><a href="http://www.website.com/page.htm">';

function getQuote(input:String, index:int=0):String {
// I declared the default index as the first one
    var matches:Array = [];
    // create an array for the matched results
    var rx:RegExp = /"(\\"|[^"])*"/g;
    // create a RegExp rule to catch all grouped chars
    // rule also includes escaped quotes
    input.replace(rx,function(a:*) {
        // if it's "etc." we want etc. only so...
        matches.push(a.substr(1,a.length-2));
    });
    // above method does not replace anything actually.
    // it just cycles in the input value and pushes
    // captured values into the matches array.
    return (index >= matches.length || index < 0) ? '' : matches[index];
}

trace('Index 0 -->',getQuote(myText))
trace('Index 1 -->',getQuote(myText,1))
trace('Index 2 -->',getQuote(myText,2))
trace('Index -1 -->',getQuote(myText,-1))
```

**Outputs:**

> Index 0 --> text-align:center;line-height:150%
>   Index 1 --> http://www.website.com/page.htm
>   Index 2 -->
>   Index -1 -->

Comment: Thanks for the information i will test these out.  To answer your question what i had in mind was to create a function GetQuote(MyText,0) where it would get "text-align:center;line-height:150%" etc.  That should be easy enough to make but i was expecting MyText.indexOf('"',0) to return 11 but MyText.indexOf('"',1) to return 39.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the simple function i made, originally i wanted to avoid using RegExp and was thinking it would work correctly but it does not return the contents that i wanted.

Comment: @zeddex I wrote a function and added that to my response.